# How do I execute command in the background + wait till it's done to execute next?

Tags: bash, shell

So let's say I have a command:

```
COMMAND
```

if I want to execute this command in the background, I do:

```
COMMAND &
```

if I want to execute 2 commands in the background, simple:

```
COMMAND1 &
COMMAND2 &
```

but sometimes what might happen is that the 2nd command gets executed first, maybe because the 1st command takes longer to execute. What if I want to execute command 1 (in the background) and wait till it is done to execute command 2? Is it possible?

Comment: For your purposes, what's the relevant difference between running something in the background and waiting, vs just running it in the foreground in the first place? (For example, are you trying to get `SIGTTIN`-on-read behavior?)

Comment: As @Charles Duffy brought up in my answer, what is your definition of "background process"?

Comment: I'm closing this for now with one of our many existing Q&A entries asking the same question, but if you clarify _why you think you need `&` at all here_, that might help to disambiguate to either allow a better duplicate to be chosen, or to allow the question to be reopened as new/unique entirely.

Comment: (It's possible you might want `{ COMMAND1; COMMAND2; } &`, backgrounding a subshell that first starts COMMAND1 and then runs COMMAND2 after COMMAND1 is complete; thus, those commands are in the foreground relative to that subshell, but in the background relative to the shell that spawned the subshell).

Comment: I have a script that executes on startup, it opens the terminal a couple of times with some programs open but it does not open in order, sometimes works correctly but sometimes it executes cmd3>cmd5>cmd1>cmd2, etc...

The script goes like this:
```
cmd1 &
sleep 1
cmd2 &
sleep 1
cmd3 &
sleep 1
cmd4 &
```
I tried using the sleep command to see if it would wait to open cmd1 before going to cmd2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You need double ampersands or a semicolon..

```
cmd1; cmd2
```

Will run `cmd1` then `cmd2` one after the other regardless if `cmd1` was successful.  But it will wait for `cmd1` to complete.

```
cmd1 && cmd2
```

With double ampersands, `cmd2` will run ONLY if `cmd1` completed with a valid exit code

Comment: Insofar as running something in the foreground is identical to running it in the background and then waiting for it, this is an accurate answer; but it's arguably also an argument for requiring the question to be reformulated to explain what distinguishing aspect of "in the background" the OP is trying to achieve. After all, we already have lots of answered questions describing how to use `foo; bar` or `foo && bar`, so if this answer were fully responsive the question would be eligible for close as duplicate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy -- Fair enough .. It was my *assumption* that OP is just meaning forked processes ... But you know what they say about assumptions ;)

Comment: It turns out that what the OP wanted was `{ cmd1; cmd2; } &` -- backgrounding both commands relative to the rest of their script, but letting the first finish before the second starts.